# Simulation of photodiode in Micro-CAP 12

Tags: simulation, spice, photodiode

I am beginner in simulation S.P.I.C.E. and I use the simulator Micro-CAP 12 to simulate an electric schematic.

I want to simulate the photodiode PIN InGaAs IG17-series and to monitor graphically the rectangular electrical impulse, at an amplitude of a few volts generated by the photodiode depending on a period of time in ns.

Please give me any advice. I do not know how to begin. The schematic is below.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Do you have a datasheet for the device? Can you turn off the dotted grid pattern to make the schematic easier to read?

Comment: Also, you can make the diagram less-wide by compacting the circuitry in width. Please also explain how you think micro-cap (or any sim) can simulate the driving of photos into the photodiode.

Comment: Hello Sirs.The more information and the  dataheet of photodiode is in this link https://www.tme.eu/en/details/ig17x1000s4i/photodiodes/laser-components/

Comment: @DragosBaciu - Hi, You have now effectively duplicated this question, with more information, [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/507360/is-it-possible-to-model-a-photodiode-pin-ingasas-in-accord-with-datasheet-in-s). Therefore I am voting to close this question as a duplicate of that one, so that people don't waste time reading *this* question, when the extra information (and one answer so far) is in *that* question. In general, repeating questions here is a bad idea, and could result in sanctions. On Stack Exchange sites, you should edit one question to add further details.